# excel 2013: COUNTIFS: text comparisons give incorrect/unexpected results

Tags: excel

Using MS Office Professional Plus 2013 on Win10:
the COUNTIFS function seems to perform string equality tests ok but inequality and lexicographic comparisons incorrectly.
In the example below, column A has data type "Text". (The function ISTEXT() confirms that).
The formula displyed in column B is evaluated in column C with the unexpected results shown in red in the screen capture.
Can this behaviour be explained?   thanks...

| DATA | FORMULA | RESULT | EXPECTED RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-11 |  |  |  |
| 2022-01-14 | =COUNTIF($A2:$A20, "=2022*") | 19 | 19 |
| 2022-01-17 | =COUNTIFS($A2:$A20, "=" & "2022-02-10") | 3 | 3 |
| 2022-02-03 | =COUNTIFS($A2:$A20, "<>" & "2022-02-10") | 19 | 16 |
| 2022-02-03 | =COUNTIFS($A2:$A20, "<" & "2022-02-10") | 0 | 10 |
| 2022-02-03 | =COUNTIFS($A2:$A20, ">" & "2022-02-10") | 0 | 6 |
| 2022-02-04 |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-07 |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-09 |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-09 |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-10 |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-10 |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-10 |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-11 |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-15 |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-15 |  |  |  |
| 2022-04-11 |  |  |  |
| 2022-07-10 |  |  |  |
| 2022-12-14 |  |  |  |

screen capture

[image]

Comment: The fact that you get `19` with `=COUNTIF($A2:$A20, "=2022*")` means your dates are stored as text and not true dates.  BTW, I get all the correct answers when they are true dates except the first which should be: `=COUNTIFS($A2:$A20,">="&"2022-01-01",$A2:$A20,"<"&"2023-01-01")`

Comment: thank you Scott.  If I change the datatype of column A to "Short Date" I get exactly the same incorrect results in Excel 2013.

Comment: Changing the datatype(format) will not change text.  you will need to convert the text to a date.  There are many methods described on this site and others on how to do that.

Comment: thank you Scott.  Explicitly converting the data from text to date solved it.  Many thanks.